# What is the maximum gym badge tier?

Tags: pokemon-go

Recently, there was a gym rework. One of the new features is that you obtain gym badges by participating in different activities related to individual gyms.

It is known that you can get Bronze, Silver and Gold gym badges (Source: Personal Experience), but I am wondering if there are any more tiers after Gold? If so, what is the amount of Badge XP required? It could possibly be something like 100 * 5 ^ ( x - 1 ) for tier x , where x_1 is bronze. Am I correct?

Answer (score 10):

The following amount of Badge-EXP (BXP) is needed to level up your Gym badge:

Gym Badge Tier // BXP needed // BXP total

- Basic // 1 BXP
- Bronze // 500 BXP // 500 BXP
- Silver // 3500 BXP // 4000 BXP
- Gold // 26,000 BXP // 30,000 BXP

Received BXP rewards for interacting with the gym:

- Adding a Pokémon to the Gym (+ 100 BXP)
- Holding a Pokémon at the Gym (+1 BXP per minute)
- Defeating a defending Pokémon (CP of Pokémon defeated divided by 10)
- Winning a Raid battle at the Gym (+ 1000 BXP)
- Feeding a Berry to a Pokémon (+ 10 BXP & 20 Stardust)

Source:
Pokemon Go source code

```
item_templates {
  template_id: "GYM_BADGE_SETTINGS"
  gym_badge_settings {
      target: 500
      target: 4000
      target: 30000
      battle_winning_score_per_defender_cp: 0.01
      gym_defending_score_per_minute: 1
      berry_feeding_score: 10
      pokemon_deploy_score: 100
      raid_battle_winning_score: 1000
      lose_all_battles_score: 5
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The gym badge tiers are the same as the medal tiers, going from basic to bronze to silver to gold, with gold being the maximum.

From [this article](https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/?toURL=https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidthier/2017/06/23/how-gym-badges-work-in-pokemon-go/&refURL=&referrer=):

> Gym badges have four levels: basic, bronze, silver and gold.

[Another source](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-06-23-pokemon-go-gym-badges-bronze-silver-gold-4819) says the same thing:

> Gym Badges come in Basic, Bronze, Silver and Gold varieties, each offering improved rewards when spinning the Photo Disc, and possibly during Raid encounters.

And, for good measure, [a third source](https://gamerant.com/pokemon-go-how-to-earn-gym-badges/):

> Each badge comes with four different tiers: basic, bronze, silver, and gold.

Comment: I think the question was more about how much "Gym XP" is needed to level up the Badges to Level Bronze, Silver and Gold.

Comment: @Hulkerman the question says "is there a tier after gold and **if so**, what is the amount of experience required to attain it?"